# System.OutOfMemoryException when reading an XML file to write to SQL Database

Tags: c#, .net, out-of-memory, sqlxml, sqlclient

Currently, I am reading from a XML file (my program previously creates in the File System) and writing the contents of that XML file into the database using the `SQLXml` Object.

We only encounter this issue once a year when annual data processing occurs.  When run the same application monthly, but because the file sizes are smaller, this error does not occur.  The Exception appears to be caused by the size of the XML file.  Initially, we had a near-100MB file causing this exception pretty consistently, and updated the code so that it would be the first file processed, and that has seemed to alleviate the issue; however, if that file went over 93MB, we began receiving the error again.

Where the application had an error this time, was after processing 63 separate files, totaling an estimated ~54MB and then attempting to process a single file of ~53MB.  When we restart the application, it will start by processing the file it failed on.

```
private SqlXml RetrieveXmlForDatabase(string filePath)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
    {
        using (var xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(reader))
        {
            return new SqlXml(xmlReader);
        }
    }
}

public void WriteFormDataXMLToDatabase(int ID, string xmlFilePath)
{
    List<SqlParameter> insertParameters = new List<SqlParameter>();

    SqlXml formDataXml = RetrieveXmlForDatabase(xmlFilePath);

    insertParameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ID", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = ID});
    insertParameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FormData", SqlDbType.Xml) { Value = formDataXml });

    ExecuteNonQuery("[spname]", insertParameters.ToArray());
}
```

The `System.OutOfMemoryException` I am receiving occurs to be happening in the `RetrieveXmlForDatabase` method.

```
========================================================================
The following Exception ocurred during application execution:
========================================================================
System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
   at System.IO.MemoryStream.set_Capacity(Int32 value)
   at System.IO.MemoryStream.EnsureCapacity(Int32 value)
   at System.IO.MemoryStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Xml.XmlEncodedRawTextWriter.EncodeChars(Int32 startOffset, Int32 endOffset, Boolean writeAllToStream)
   at System.Xml.XmlEncodedRawTextWriter.FlushBuffer()
   at System.Xml.XmlEncodedRawTextWriter.RawText(Char* pSrcBegin, Char* pSrcEnd)
   at System.Xml.XmlEncodedRawTextWriter.RawText(String s)
   at System.Xml.XmlEncodedRawTextWriter.WriteFullEndElement(String prefix, String localName, String ns)
   at System.Xml.XmlWellFormedWriter.WriteFullEndElement()
   at System.Xml.XmlWriter.WriteNode(XmlReader reader, Boolean defattr)
   at System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlXml.CreateMemoryStreamFromXmlReader(XmlReader reader)
   at System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlXml..ctor(XmlReader value)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.CoerceValue(Object value, MetaType destinationType, Boolean& coercedToDataFeed, Boolean& typeChanged, Boolean allowStreaming)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.GetCoercedValue()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.Validate(Int32 index, Boolean isCommandProc)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.SetUpRPCParameters(_SqlRPC rpc, Int32 startCount, Boolean inSchema, SqlParameterCollection parameters)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.BuildRPC(Boolean inSchema, SqlParameterCollection parameters, _SqlRPC& rpc)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
========================================================================
```

The current workaround is letting the application fail in this instance and then re-executing the application.  While this is okay because we have checks to prevent data-loss, it would be preferred if the error didn't occur in the first place.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how to prevent this.

Comment: Check how memory consumption develops during the execution your program. If it appears your system has still enough free memory when the OutOfMemoryException occurs, your program could suffer from fragmentation of the large object heap. If the OutOfMemoryException occurs when the available free memory is going towards zero, you will need to check how and where your program allocates memory and where it might fail to free the memory again (like, holding abandoned arrays in static collections, for example...)

Comment: The sizes of the XML files don't tell us much about your problem, but you could look at what makes the small XML files different from the larger ones and thus perhaps gain a hint of what parts of your program might be involved in causing the problem...

Comment: Also note that the code throwing the OutOfMemoryException is not necessarily the offender. Unless the cause is LOH fragmentation, you will need to inspect your whole program to find places that greedily hoard memory (profiling your program might help in this respect)